# Why does HTML data transforms after Response.Redirect()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, redirect, response.redirect

I'm using Session to pass data from one page to another. The data contains HTML and when I display it in the other page, I see that it's different.

This is how I put data in Session:

```
Session["omschrijving"] = Server.UrlEncode(lblOmschrijving.Text);
```

This is how I get data from Session:

```
ftbOmschrijving.Text = (string)Session["omschrijving"];
```

Can someone help me please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since you `UrlEncode` your data you need to decode it when reading.

```
ftbOmschrijving.Text = Server.UrlDecode(Session["omschrijving"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to decode encoded data.

·         HttpUtility.UrlEncode()  - to encode data

·         HttpUtility.UrlDecode () - to decode data

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this

```
Session["omschrijving"] = lblOmschrijving.Text;
```

and the same to retrieve

```
ftbOmschrijving.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["omschrijving"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned, you don't even need to URL encode that data, since you are putting it in a `Session` variable. It is an unnecessary process, which takes valuable processor time.

UrlEncoding is used when you put the String value in an Url, i.e. if you would Redirect to a certain url.

Drop the `UrlEncode()`, and `UrlDecode()` and you should still be fine, and have saved a little time in page load, and caused a little less frustration for those poor low bandwidth surfers !

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
ftbOmschrijving.Text = Server.UrlDecode(Session["omschrijving"]);
```

Comment: I was to quick :-) Didn't see that i made a fault.